# how do I use the text in a txt file, as the password to protect and unprotect sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I create a text file in "C:\Users\Public\Music\Do Not Delete -- Sourcefile for Salary Sheet.txt"
That txt file has a 1 line password.
I want to use that password and merge it with `ActiveSheet.Protect Password:=""`

i want to be able to use the string in the txt file to protect/unprotect a sheet.

I've tried the following

```vb
Dim hFile As Long
Dim strFile As String
Dim strData As String * 4

hFile = FreeFile
strFile = "C:\Users\Public\Music\Do Not Delete -- Sourcefile for Salary Sheet.txt"
Open strFile For Binary Access Read As hFile Len = 4
Get hFile, 1, strData

Activesheet.protect.password=(strData)
```

The result of these and various different variations is the following-

> "strData" is used as the password

> Sheet is locked without a password<

Nothing seems to work.
Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One function (GetPassword) retrieve the password from the file and the SheetProtection switch the protection

```
Public Sub test()
    
    SheetProtection True
    
End Sub

Public Sub SheetProtection(active As Boolean)
    
    Dim sh          As Worksheet
    Dim password    As String
    
    Set sh = ActiveSheet
    password = GetPassword()
    
    If active Then
        sh.Protect password
    Else
        sh.Unprotect password
    End If
    
End Sub

Public Function GetPassword() As String

    Dim ff          As Long
    Dim fileName    As String
    Dim password    As String
    
    fileName = "C:\Users\Public\Music\Do Not Delete -- Sourcefile for Salary Sheet.txt"
    ff = FreeFile
    
    Open fileName For Binary As #ff
        password = Space(LOF(ff))
        Get #ff, , password
    Close #ff
    
    GetPassword = password
    
End Function
```

Comment: Can you tell how to run the code? Which one macro should i run?

Comment: SheetProtection True to protect the sheet, SheetProtection False to Unprotect it